# Retrieving entity data in views with dynamic (per-row) relationship

Tags: entities, views

I have custom entity 'entitystatus' that holds 'entity_id' reference and 'entity_type' field.
Now I need to build a view that will display Entity statuses attached to different entity types (i.e. nodes and users) with entity titles:

```
| status | entity type | entity title |
---------------------------------------
| stat1  | node        | Node Title   |
---------------------------------------
| stat2  | user        | John Doe     |
---------------------------------------
```

So, I need dynamic table and field relation.
I'm trying to build custom relationship handler, but it seems that it can't handle individual per-row data. 
Is it possible to fetch any entity-related fields in that hybrid view?
What is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: Is there some missing information here? I can't see how the title relates to the question...

Comment: I agree with @bhotel, please update the title or question. Could you also provide the View that you currently have? At the moment, it's a bit hard for me to understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about this error! It's previous unposted question title cached with my browser...